# column deletion in HIVE without code change?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, oozie

QUESTION:
We have a table of 4 columns.
For suppose in future, if we don't require 2 columns among them, how can we remove them without doing any code changes in real time project?

Comment: Depends on the file format - CSV is positional, ORC should use the name to find actual position in each file, Parquet... might depend on Hive & Parquet version plus whether files were written by Hive/Impala/Spark, AVRO I don't know.

Comment: Plus, old partitions keep their original structure by default, while new partitions inherit the structure that is current (via ALTER TABLE ** COLUMN) when they are created.

Comment: PS: I don't undetstand what the `oozie` tag has to do in a question about Hive tables and "real time" apps.